# Powershell Parse logfile and add timestamps when missing

Tags: powershell, replace, timestamp, edit

Given a log file like this:

```
10:36:36:891 blah blah 1
10:36:36:891 blah blah 2
  blah blah 3
10:37:00:231 blah blah 4
```

I would like to parse the log file, looking at each line to determine if there is a timestamp.  If not, add (prepend) the previous timestamp to the line and keep going to the next line, then ultimately save the log file with the changes.

I'm new to PowerShell but probably need to start with something like:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\file.txt)
 if($line -match $regex){
   # Work here
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your plan sounds solid - so what do you need help with? Writing a regex that can split each line into an (optional) timestamp and a message line?

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about it.  I think the timestamp format is typically hh:mm:ss:### so I just need to read the first of the line and see if it matches (I need help with that), if it does store it as a variable, and move to next line. Then if it doesnt match, read the line into a variable, then replace the line by concatenating the variable + the line and inserting it into the log.  (I think this is what the process would be, but don't know the syntax to use.  All of this is way beyond my experience) And I am fine outputting to a separate file to preserve the original.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that any line without a timestamp needs to have the previous timestamp used as a prefix?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Not every line has a timestamp.  I want to add the timestamps where missing.  The end goal is to be able to mash several logfiles together into one big one sorted by timestamp, which cannot be done if there are lines that don't have the timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.4) with the `-Regex` and `-File` flags. As an example, using the data provided in question:

```bash
@'
10:36:36:891 blah blah 1
10:36:36:891 blah blah 2
  blah blah 3
10:37:00:231 blah blah 4
'@ | Set-Content .\test.log

$parsedLog = switch -File .\test.log -Regex {
    '^(?:[0-9]{2}:){3}[0-9]{3}' { $_ } # if the line starts with a timestamp, output it as is
    Default { '{0} {1}' -f $Matches[0], $_.TrimStart() } # else, prepend the previous timestamp
}
$parsedLog | Set-Content .\test.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes a specific format for the timestamp at the beginning of the line.

```
foreach ($line in (Get-Content .\file.txt)) {
    if ($line -match '^(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}).*') {
        Write-Host "The timestamp is $($Matches[1])"
    }
}
```

Do you need to convert the timestamp into a `[datetime]` object?

Comment: foreach ($line in (Get-Content  '.\file.txt')) {
        if ($line -match '^(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}).*') {
            Write-Host $line
        }
        else {Write-Host "missing" + $line
    }
    }

This works so far (sorry.. can't get formatting to work right)

Comment: I think I'm getting closer but this doesnt work
<pre><code>
    foreach ($line in (Get-Content  '.\file.txt')) {

    if ($line -match '^(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}).*') {

    $timestamp = $line -match '^(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}.'

    Write-Host $line

    }

    else {Write-Host $timestamp + $line

    }
</code></pre>
}

Comment: @JasonJensen, could you say more about "doesn't work"? What does it do?